# Regex exclude .html from string

Tags: regex, django

I am stuck with creation of regex matching my needs.

Regex should include beginning of the string but not the ending (.html)
Example:
`company.html` should convert into `company`

My attempt:

```
url(r'^(?P<page>.+\.html)$', some_view)
```

Is there any chance someone could advice me on this one? I need to prepare my django urls to expect over 50 companies names and it seems to be the easiest way to keep my code DRY.

Answer (score 3):

Simply exclude it out of the capture group:

```
url(r'^(?P<page>.+)\.html$', some_view)
```

(capture group in boldface).

The part between the brackets that starts with `(?P<var>...)` is the *capture group*, the content that is matched with that pattern, will be injected into `var`.

But you can add extra parts outside the capture group, that thus are *required* by the pattern, but not captured in the variable.

That being said, typically in Django apps, one does not add noise like extensions, etc. Why would you add weird characters to a URL that a non-technical person does not understand at all?

Comment: The idea was to prepare GenericView, which handles all `example.com/company` pages which are basically identical, however they need to exist separately. I thought I am gonna create 50 templates with 1 base template and handle them this way. I want user to   type `www.example.com/apple` but my view looks like `self.temlate=page`. That's why i need to strip the .HTML part

Comment: Commenting on my phone is not so handy as I expected -_- Is the part `.+` needed by any means to match my needs here? And btw, thanks for the quick answer, appreciate !

Comment: @michael93pl: yes, since the `.+` matches one or more characters, the ones that will result in the `apple` of `apple.html`.